# How can I echo a value/variable in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

Disclaimer: I'm very new to this.

I have a number which I retrieved using the count command and now I want to output it to a .txt file using "do shell script echo."

My code so far:

```
tell application "Things3"
    set todayToDos to to dos of list "Today"
    count todayToDos
    do shell script "echo todayToDos > /Users/nonefirstnonelast/Desktop/Things.txt"
end tell
```

Console output is:

```
""
without do shell script "echo todayToDos > /Users/nonefirstnonelast/Desktop/Things.txt" line it is: 27
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the result of the `count` line to a variable. Then you have to coerce the integer to text and insert the value of the variable in the shell script line.

```
tell application "Things3"
    set todayToDos to to dos of list "Today"
    set numberOfTodos to count todayToDos
end tell
do shell script "echo " & (numberOfTodos as text) & " > /Users/nonefirstnonelast/Desktop/Things.txt"
```